# How do I distribute values across months? #R

Tags: r, date, tidyverse, lubridate

Currently, my data has a columne for start_date and a column for end_date.

For each time period (start-end), there are values like number of deaths of side a and side b. I want to divide the values across months.

Sometimes, it started and ended in the same month and year (let's say March 2020), and if deaths_a is 10, then I want to have 10 for March 2020.

Sometimes, it started in let's say March and ended in April. If deaths_a is 10, then I want to have  5 for March and 5 for April.

How should I approach this?

Thank you!

[image: My current data has year_month]

Comment: Just a suggestion: Use floor date by month for both `date_start` and `date_end` in each row e.g. `floor_date(dat$date_start, 'month')`. Check if they are the same. If not, split the row into two. Actual implementation depend on how comfortable you are with data wrangling.

Answer (score 0):

Using Lubridate package will solve. Assume you always have increasing order of time.

```
library(lubridate)

##input
date_start = "1995-03-30"
date_end = "1995-04-01"
death_a = 80

year_diff = year(ymd(date_end)) - year(ymd(date_start))
month_diff = month(ymd(date_end)) - month(ymd(date_start))
death_distri_month = death_a / (year_diff*12 + month_diff + 1 )  # 40
```

Also works for negative "month_diff" since we assume an increasing sequence of time.

```
##input
date_start = "1995-09-30"
date_end = "1996-01-01"
death_a = 80

year_diff = year(ymd(date_end)) - year(ymd(date_start))
month_diff = month(ymd(date_end)) - month(ymd(date_start))
death_distri_month = death_a / (year_diff*12 + month_diff + 1 )  # 16
```